# How to make a suttering window in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx

I need a window that can be move up down in my main window. Mainly IDE(IntelliJ, CodeBlock, Netbeans etc) [output window feature](https://youtu.be/nBdyLzsSZIA).

I use `TitledPane`. By using this I can give a height that is expanded when I click the pane, but I can't expand the pane in any height.

see this - not expanded:

[image: not expanded]

and this- expanded:

[image: expanded]

My code is [here](https://github.com/al2helal/TextPad/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alhelal/textpad/Options.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SplitPane`. I guess this is what you want. You can learn more from the following link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(new Pane(), new Pane());
        splitPane.setDividerPositions(0.5);
        splitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(splitPane,400,400));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a added a sample code to the answer. It's nothing much just a `SplitPane` with two emtpy `Pane`. Hope it helps you

Comment: would you give me a suggestion that how can I replace my `TitledPane` with `SplitePane`.

Comment: You haven't provided any code to your post. So it's hard for me to realize what you tried and what you want to do